# How to determine plurality of a word in Python without using Inflect or NLTK?

Tags: python, nlp

I am writing a program using Python which reads a list of words and needs to determine the plurality of each one. I tried using Inflect but, as far as I can tell, it does not provide any great methods for determining the plurality of a generic word. I used the singular_noun and plural_noun methods but they both require that the word to be inflected be both a noun and plural/singular, respectively. According to documentation:

> "All of the plural... plural inflection methods take the word to be inflected as their first argument and return the corresponding inflection. **Note that all such methods expect the singular form of the word. The results of passing a plural form are undefined (and unlikely to be correct).** Similarly, the si... singular inflection method expects the plural form of the word."

I have also tried using NLTK pos_tag but it is too inaccurate.

Is there a better Inflect method or a different Python package that can take any word of any part of speech and accurately determine its plurality?

Answer (score -2):

```
import inflect
engine = inflect.engine()
plural = engine.plural(your_string)
```